# Comparing and Filtering two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter, array-splice

I've been trying to implement a function where given with two arrays,

**array1**'s elements is used as conditions to filter out elements in **array2**.

For instance:

```
array1= [apple, grapes, oranges]

array2= [potato, pears, grapes, berries, apples, oranges]
```

After feeding into a function, array2 should have elements as such:

```
filter_twoArrays(array1,array2)

array2= [grapes, apples, oranges]
```

I've tried the following code, using for loops and array.splice(), but the problem I am seeing is that when I use the splice method, it seems that it changes the lengths of array2 in the for loop:

```
function filter_twoArrays(filter,result){

  for(i=0; i< filter.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j< result.length; j++){
      if(filter[i] !== result[j]){
        result.splice(j,1)
      }
    }
  }
```

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated on how to refine the filter function

cheers!

Comment: In php you could use `array_intersect`, but your code seems a bit like JS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: Is the order of elements in result array2 important to you?

Answer (score 30):

You can use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as follow

```js
var array1 = ['apples', 'grapes', 'oranges', 'banana'],
  array2 = ['potato', 'pears', 'grapes', 'berries', 'apples', 'oranges'];

var intersection = array1.filter(function(e) {
  return array2.indexOf(e) > -1;
});

console.log(intersection);
```

You can also add this method on Array prototype and call it directly on array

```js
Array.prototype.intersection = function(arr) {
  return this.filter(function(e) {
    return arr.indexOf(e) > -1;
  });
};

var array1 = ['apples', 'grapes', 'oranges', 'banana'],
  array2 = ['potato', 'pears', 'grapes', 'berries', 'apples', 'oranges'];

var intersection = array1.intersection(array2);
console.log(intersection);
```

Comment: With ES6 `arr1.filter(e => arr2.includes(e))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `some`, like this:

```
let newArray = array2.filter(
      (array22) => !array1.some((array11) => array11.id === array22._id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is a porting of the function array_intersect php. Should be good for you
http://phpjs.org/functions/array_intersect/

```
function array_intersect(arr1) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_intersect/
  // original by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //        note: These only output associative arrays (would need to be
  //        note: all numeric and counting from zero to be numeric)
  //   example 1: $array1 = {'a' : 'green', 0:'red', 1: 'blue'};
  //   example 1: $array2 = {'b' : 'green', 0:'yellow', 1:'red'};
  //   example 1: $array3 = ['green', 'red'];
  //   example 1: $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2, $array3);
  //   returns 1: {0: 'red', a: 'green'}

  var retArr = {},
    argl = arguments.length,
    arglm1 = argl - 1,
    k1 = '',
    arr = {},
    i = 0,
    k = '';

  arr1keys: for (k1 in arr1) {
    arrs: for (i = 1; i < argl; i++) {
      arr = arguments[i];
      for (k in arr) {
        if (arr[k] === arr1[k1]) {
          if (i === arglm1) {
            retArr[k1] = arr1[k1];
          }
          // If the innermost loop always leads at least once to an equal value, continue the loop until done
          continue arrs;
        }
      }
      // If it reaches here, it wasn't found in at least one array, so try next value
      continue arr1keys;
    }
  }

  return retArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [2, 3];

arr1.filter(e => arr2.indexOf(e) > -1 ? false : true); // [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Came here some week back to find a solution to a problem like this but its a pity I couldn't get what I wanted, but now I figured it out in a more simple way. using the arrow function, *.filter()* method and **.includes()** method.

Declare an arrow function that takes in two arguments:

```
const filterTwoArrays = (string1, string2) => string1.filter(item => string2.includes(item));

console.log(filterTwoArrays(array1, array2)).
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged javascript here is the solution.

```
function f1(x, y) {
    var t = y.slice(0);
    var r = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] === y[j]) {
                [].push.apply(r, t.splice(j, 1));
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(r)
    y.length = 0;
    [].push.apply(y, r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way based on your code

```
function array_filter(filter, result) {
    var filterLen = filter.length;
    var resultLen = result.length;

    for (i = 0; i < resultLen; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < filterLen; j++) {
            if (!contains(filter, result[i]))
                result.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

//Return boolean depending if array 'a' contains item 'obj'
function contains(array, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark the items which are to be filtered out via `delete result[index]` manipulate them as needed.

*JavaScript*

```js
window.onload = runs;

function runs() {
    var array1 = ["apples", "grapes", "oranges"];
    var array2 = ["potato", "pears", "grapes", "berries", "apples", "oranges"];
    var result = filter_twoArrays(array1, array2);

    function filter_twoArrays(filter, result) {
        var i = 0,
            j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var FLAG = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < filter.length; j++) {
                if (filter[j] == result[i]) {
                    FLAG = 1;
                }
            }
            if (FLAG == 0) delete result[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i] !== undefined)
            body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML + result[i] + " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

const func = array1.filter(item => array2.includes(item));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [2, 3]; 
const finalArray = arr1.filter(person => arr2.some(person2 => person.includes(person2)))
```